# How to display Firestore's specific doc in particular indexes using flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In my Firestore i have a collection of posts and in this posts fields there is a specific field with `advertize` which has a bool value. so in my flutter app after fetching and displaying it i needed to display ads where that `advertize` field is true in indexes where the indexes [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25,...] and so on meet. how can i do that?

```
FirestoreListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          query: queryPost,
          pageSize: 5,
          emptyBuilder: (context) {
            return const Center(
              child: Text("No Posts to Display"),
            );
          },
          itemBuilder: (context, snapshot) {
            final post = snapshot.data();
            return Column(
              children: [
                PostBox(
                  height: _height,
                  width: _width,
                  doc: post,
                  id: snapshot.id,
                  url: post['url'],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: _height * 0.03,
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        )
```

Comment: To learn how to display documents from Firestore in Flutter, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#dart.  To learn how to filter what documents Firestore returns, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#dart_1

Comment: Does above suggestion was helpful?